# Xcode 11.3.1 not showing NSObject subclass members in debugger

Tags: xcode, debugging

I don't know what has happened but suddenly the variable members of classes that inherit from NSObjects no longer show up in the debugger at break points. When the triangle next to the class is opened the only thing visible is a line:baseNSObject@0 (NSObject)

[image]

I have set the Build Settings - Optimization Level for debugger to None[-O0] and in scheme the run setting is set to Debug as recommended in the apple recommendation document.

[https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1947/_index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SHRZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved.
I had quite a few old break points in the code. Some active some inactive. I deleted them all and then reset the break point again. Suddenly everything start to work as expected and I could see the class members in the debugger. 
Reza